# ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Tags: angular

I am using angular 5:

```
build : ng build --prod
```

Error:

```
10% building modules 4/6 modules 2 active ...ules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.14, but autoprefixer uses
5.2.18.
```

Perhaps this is the source of the error below.

```
69% building modules 768/771 modules 3 active ...ules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.14, but autoprefixer uses
5.2.18.
```

Perhaps this is the source of the error below.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
```

Comment: Same issue here after updating my packages today...

Answer (score 3):

It worked to me:

1. Edit node_modules\bootstrap\package.json
2. Remove these lines:

> "last 1 major version",
>
> ">= 1%",